# Google Play not passing full referrer string?

Tags: android, google-play

Why am I only seeing part of my referrer string in my INSTALL_REFERRER BroadcastReceiver?

LogCat shows this:

```
START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=market://details?id=com.myapp&referrer=val1=1&val2=2
```

But when I log the "referrer" value in my BroadcastReceiver from the intent, I only get:

```
val1=1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the following URL `market://details?id=com.myapp&referrer=val1=1&val2=2`, the variables will be split like this:

- `referrer` = `val1=1`
- `val2` = `2`

To get the referrer to contain `val1=1&val2=2`, you'll want to escape the `&`. The URL will look like

`market://details?id=com.myapp&referrer=val1=1%26val2=2`

Comment: This is fine for my 2.x devices but on 4.x when I visit market://details?id=com.myapp&referrer=val1=1%26val2=2, the intent shows an unencoded referrer.